# Finding First and Follow in LL(1) Parsing with Left Recursion

Tags: recursion, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm new to Stackoverflow and I thought this will be a best place to clarify some of my doubts.

I have been searching around for finding first and follow when there is left recursion.  Some of them have been saying to remove left recursion first before finding the first and follow sets.

However, is it possible to find the first and follow sets when there is left recursion without removing left recursion?

Therefore my question is if lets say in LL(1) parsing what would be the First and Follow for **Stmt** without removing left recursion?

```
Stmt -> Stmt Stmt +
  | Stmt Stmt -
  | number
```

Comment: If there's left recursion in the grammar, it's not an LL(1) grammar. You can't apply LL(1) parsing algorithms to a non-LL(1) grammar.

Comment: @sepp2k So it is not possible to compute the first/follow sets for that particular grammar when there is left recursion?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to compute the sets, but the computation of the FIRST set requires a little more care than it would with an LL(1) grammar. In this case, it's quite obvious, though: Since `Stmt` cannot be empty (every production includes at least one terminal), the only terminal which can start a `Stmt` is `number`. Given that fact, computing the FOLLOW set is also trivial.